# SSRS auto-numbering but with letters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, formatting, reporting

Maybe this is easy and I am missing something, but I am making a SSRS report that has a bunch of records, and then each record can have multiple records associated with it. What I want is the report to dynamically generate numbering for the parent record, and letter-numbering for the childeren. For Example:

1. Parent Item One 
   a) first child
   b) second child
2. Parent Item Two 
    a) first child 
    b) second child 
    c) third child 
   I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with the SSRS plugin, but I also have BIDS 2008. I was able to generate the parent numbering by using this function:  =RunningValue(Fields!ParentItem.Value, CountDistinct, "ParentGroup"). I tried using the numbering tool from the toolbar, but it just inserts "1. " in front of every record, regardless of what item number it is. The real trouble is getting the function to generate letters instead of numbers. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out a way. I used the same method as I did for the parent numbering on the children for the value of a hidden text box. Then I made another text box where I wanted the letter-numbering to appear, and used a switch expression to set the value based on the value of the hidden text box. Probably not the best way to do this, but it works

Answer (score 1):

I have created two functions one for parent row number and second for child row number(i.e. a b c..).This functions are in report properties->Code. The functions are as follows

For Parent row number:-

```
Dim private count as integer = 0
Dim private iniRow as integer = 0
Public function ParentRowNum(Byval rowNum as integer) as integer
   if iniRow = 0 then
      iniRow = rowNum
   end if

   if rowNum = iniRow then
       count = 0
   end if
   count = count + 1
   Return count
End function
```

For Child row number:-

```
Dim private count_ascii as integer = 96
Dim private iniRow_sub as integer = 0
Public function ChildRowNum(Byval rowNum_sub as integer) as string
   if iniRow_sub= 0 then
       iniRow_sub= rowNum_sub
   end if

   if rowNum_sub= iniRow_sub then           
       count_ascii =96
   end if

  count_ascii =count_ascii +1
   Return Chr(count_ascii )
End function
```

Expressions are as follows :-

```
=Code.ParentRowNum(RowNumber(Nothing))
=Code.ChildRowNum(RowNumber(Nothing))
```

Hope this code helps..